# Строка на входе, нужно узнать является ли числом

Tags: java, double

```
     static boolean itsNumber(String s ){
           if (s.length() == 0) return false;
            char[] cha = s.toCharArray();
        boolean flag = false;//если больше одной точки то тру
            for(int i =0; i < cha.length;i++)
            {
                char c = cha[i];
                //если символ "-" не первый  или символ является не числовым ... и дальше пытаюсь обработать наличие точки, но не могу
                if((i!=0 && c == '-') || (!Character.isDigit(c)) || flag && (c=='.' && (i==0||i==cha.length)))    return false;
                if((c=='.' && (i==0||i==cha.length))) flag = true;//ставлю флаг true, если уже точка поймана одна, и она не первый и не последний символ.
            }
    return true;
}
```

Обработка точки не работает правильно, голову сломал. Не могу понять как написать надо. Мне нужно чтобы double обработал как число, а программа из-за точки пишет, что это стринг. Помогите обработать корректно double.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

можно регуляркой проверить еще

```
static boolean itsNumber(String s ){
   return s.matches("\\d+\\.\\d+") || s.matches("\\d+")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static boolean itsNumber(String s) {
    try {
        Double.parseDouble(s);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Этот способ мне известен, но мне хотелось бы чтобы именно проверка точки обрабатывалась. Это ключевой момент для меня в этом задании.